# How to get only date part (dd/mm/yyyy) of a date object without time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to create date object without time info like `23/09/2019`.

I already tried many solutions like;

```
new Date(d.setHours(0,0,0,0))
new Date(dateString).toUTCString().split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ')
new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate())
new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate())
```

However, all of this either give me string or date with time `Tue Aug 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300`

I want to get this `23/09/2019` as a date object. When I write `typeof result` it should return date.
I know js `Date` object stores date and time but 
Is it possible to get something like this?

Comment: `d.toLocaleDateString()`? I mean, a date object will always output the date and time, but if you want just the date, then use the method that is there for just such a purpose

Comment: It will always contain time information, but you are not forced to use/print them.

Comment: A solution may be in using a dedicated small library called "moment.js" which is very useful to manipulate dates : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @EddiGordo I know moment.js but it also returns string not date object

Comment: @hrrs if you want to display `dd/mm/yyyy`, you need to convert it to string. `new Date()` is a Date object and it has nothing to with `dd/mm/yyyy` or any other format

Comment: @adiga Yes you are right, I know it but I wonder if there is another way of getting this as date object.

Comment: You can overwrite `Date.prototype.toString` with your own function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fkhoys28/

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem and are approaching it from the wrong end. A Date object always contains time information, that’s part of the spec. If you want to print it without the time, use a string method that does so. If you want to compare dates without the time being a factor, use comparison methods for this (such as `moment(date).isSame(otherDate, ’day’)`).

Comment: Actually, there's no type for `Date`. If you want to check the type is `Date` object, you are in a wrong way. You may want to compare its instance using `instance of`.

Comment: Date objects don't store date and time. They have an offset from the ECMAScript epoch in milliseconds (a time value), that's it. There are also some methods for getting various values, such as UTC and local date and time based on the time value and system timezone settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Date - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods) for Date methods to see more details. You can compose the date components however you like.

If you want the date/month/year, you just need to call those methods:

```
function zeroPad(n) {
  return n < 10 ? '0'+n : n;
}
var d = new Date();
var s = zeroPad(d.getDate()) + '/' + zeroPad(d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
console.log(s);
```

See also `getUTCDate`, `getUTCMonth`, `getUTCFullYear` for UTC.